# What causes the error "too many simultaneous non-pooled connection attempts" error when using SqlConnection?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlconnection

I need to understand the cause of this error in a .NET application that tests connections to multiple databases at once.

> Timeout attempting to open the connection.  The time period elapsed
> prior to attempting to open the connection has been exceeded.  This
> may have occurred because of too many simultaneous non-pooled
> connection attempts.

I have a list of database URL (hundreds) that we manage. The tool allows for connecting to all of them at once and running the same query in parallel across all instances, then aggregates the results. The connections are displayed in a tree view, and the application tests the connection to all databases at once and colors green the ones that succeed. It does this in the background, so the user can see which connections are valid and can select the database they want to query. For the connection test on individual databases, we use a non-pooled connection string, and we immediately dispose the connection after it has been successfully opened.

I found that as we add more databases, I start to see the aforementioned error, but I don't understand where the limitation is. Obviously it's not a connection limit on individual databases (or even a limit from an individual client) because the pool itself can support hundreds of connections, and we're *generally* making only one connection to each database from this client to test the connection.

Is it possible that .NET has a global limit to how many outbound SQL connections it can try to make at once from a single process? For the sake of argument, assume there are no more than 100 databases in the list. Another possibility is that some of the database URLs we list actually refer to the same database; for example, we may have 10 clients on a single database with 10 distinct URLs that all ultimately resolve to the same database. Could attempting (N) non-pooled connections at once to the same database from the same application (via different tasks/threads) cause this error?

Comment: Are you using Windows authentication?

Comment: SQL Server authentication. I create a bunch of Tasks by calling OpenAsync across all the database connections (SqlConnection instances). Most complete. Many fail with that error. If I right-click an individual database node in the tree and have it re-test the connection, it opens fine. It's only when opening many connections to many databases at once that some fail. I suspect the problem is limited to cases where I'm making multiple non-pooled connections to the same database at once, but I'm not sure, and I don't know why such a limitation might exist.

Comment: SQL Server will happily receive 32767 simultaneous connections. On the client side `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` objects that should be used in `using` blocks so that they are closed (or handed back to connection pools) and disposed of correctly. It sounds like you might have missed one/a few. Eventually the client will run out of available connections and get errors such as the one posted. Connection pools are keyed based on the connection string, so there will effectively be a pool for each database mentioned in Database/Initial Catalog parameters.

Comment: No, I haven't missed disposing any connections. My post literally says the that the connection is disposed immediately after opening it. It's in a using block.  I know how many connections SQL server supports, and that's why this situation is so strange. The limit appears to be client-side limitation connecting to the same server with non-pooled connections.